# How do I return data from database based on user input on android?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I already have connected my application with my data base with php using a url. However, I have a text field and a button. The text field is supposed to take in input which will then be used for the mysql command "Select  from table" . How can I accomplish this?

This is the code I have right now:

```
public List<Si> getData(){
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/functions/return_locations.php";

    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    data.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Si info = new Si();
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("name")) info.title = jsonObject.getString("name");
                        data.add(info);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("database", "no locations returned");
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    return data;

}
```

Here is the php code I have right now:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json ');

   $dbhost = '127.0.0.1';
   $dbuser = 'root';
   $dbpass = 'pass123';

   $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);

   if(! $conn ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM Locations';
   mysql_select_db('inscope');
   $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

   if(! $retval ) {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
   }

   while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($retval)){

        $json[]  = $rows;
}
   echo json_encode($json);
   mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it in the url as a GET parameter like this:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/functions/return_locations.php?input=" + userInput;
```

to get that in php add this code before your sql query

```
$input = $_GET['input'];
```

to get another input:

```
$input2 = $_GET['input2']; // Note that you enter the string inside the GET function in the url
```

then your url should look like this:

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/functions/return_locations.php?input=" + userInput + "&input2=" + input2;
```

Comment: I see, how would I handle multiple inputs?

Comment: You control that in your php script.. are you familiar with declaring variables with GET in php?